# htaccess redirecting using both subdomain and path parameters

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I have a small website and I want to use `.htaccess` to redirect urls from this

http://user-38273.example.com/docum-3726.html

to this

```
http://example.com/show.php?userid=38273&docid=3726
```

Of course, instead of 38273 and 3726 there can be any numbers

I found some redirect examples on stackoverflow but only on how to redirect the path, or the subdomain, and I couldn't get them both in the same line

I tried this but is not working

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^user-(.*)$docum-(.*) http://example.com/show.php?userid=%1&docid=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

How can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Give the following a try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?user-(\d+)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^docum-(\d+)\.html$ /show.php?userid=%1&docid=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you for help but is not working :(  can you please explain what the parts of it mean? the RewriteCond contains the condition or rewrite, but what is [NC] and [L] means?